# Did Jesus believe and teach that God loved all people?

Tags: life-of-jesus, old-testament, new-testament, love, gentile

Jesus was raised as a Jew in a Jewish culture. All Jewish male children, starting at age 5, were taught the Torah and were required to memorized parts of Torah, along with how to read and write.  After a period of time, after the boys were familiar with the core essentials of Judaism, some of the boys would be recognized as superior in intelligence and they would continue in study, with the idea that they would become a rabbi, a teacher of Scripture.  The other boys would be released to return home and learn the trade of their fathers.

According to Scripture, we know that Jesus was an exceptional student and had a superior understanding of Scripture, Lk 2:40,50 and Lk 2 46-47. Since there was no "New Testament" at that time, everything Jesus knew and taught came straight from the Old Testament.

In the Old Testament, we see that God only loved the Jews and any Gentile that became a proselyte. There is not one verse in the Old Testament that states that God loves/loved all people.  Beyond that, the Old Testament also teaches that there are certain types of people that God hates:

- Psalm 5:5-6: The foolish will not stand in thy sight. You hate all workers of iniquity.  You will destroy liars, He will abhor the bloody and deceitful man.
- Psalm 11:5-6: The Lord tests the righteous: but the wicked and him that loveth violence His soul hates. Upon the wicked He will rain snares, fire and brimstone. A horrible tempest will be their portion...
- Proverbs 6:16-19: the proud, liars, murderers, those who devise wicked plans, those who are quick to do evil, false witnesses and those that gossip (with the intent of causing chaos or spreading lies.)

Jesus did not come and proclaim "new teaching.":

- John 17:6: "...My doctrine is not mine, but he that sent me."
- John 8:28: "I do nothing of myself, but as my Father has taught me, I speak these things."
- John 12:50: "...Whatever I speak is what the Father said unto me."
- John 7:28 "...I have not come in my own authority or will..."

Since Jesus only taught from the Old Testament, God never changes and there is no Old Testament teaching that God loves all people, is it even remotely possible that Jesus would introduce a completely new and strange teaching that contradicts what God clearly laid out in the Old Testament?

Comment: So, you are saying that God, today, loves only Jews and Jewish proselytes ? This question needs _considerable_ clarity and _considerable_ further detail.

Comment: This may be another quote from yourself _John 3:16 does not mean God loves everybody! You can believe what you want, but Scripture does not teach this myth._ [Quora - Bob Corrigan](https://www.quora.com/profile/Bob-Corrigan-1/).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We are quite different from other sites and you may find it helpful to take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 7):

#### Old Testament

Even in the Old Testament since Abraham, God has planned to bless "all nations" (that is, Gentiles) through Abraham's descendants, which includes Jesus. [Gen 22:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+22%3A15-18&version=CSB):

> And **all the nations of the earth will be blessed by your offspring** because you have obeyed my command.

Furthermore, once Abraham's descendants occupied Canaan, one of the covenant stipulations is how they should love "foreigners" / "aliens" (i.e. Gentiles).
[Lev 19:33-34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+19%3A33-34&version=CSB):

> <sup>33</sup> “When an alien resides with you in your land, you must not oppress him. <sup>34</sup> You will regard the alien who resides with you as the native-born among you. **You are to love him as yourself, for you were aliens in the land of Egypt**; I am the Lord your God.

#### Jesus's Ministry

Yes, before resurrection Jesus ministered only to the Jews; all the apostles were Jews too.  The story in [Matt 15:21-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+15%3A21-28&version=CSB) (A Gentile Mother's Faith) made it clear. Matt 15:24:

> [Jesus] replied, “I was sent only to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.”

But Jesus *did* help the Gentile Mother and praised her for her faith (v. 28)  There are other hints as well that Jesus loves the Gentiles.  Quote from *GotQuestions* article [Did Jesus come only for the Jews and not the Gentiles?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-Jews-only.html):

> The fact that Jesus helped the Canaanite woman, even though His mission was to the Jews, is a significant detail in the Gospel narrative. Throughout His earthly ministry, Jesus gave other indications that His power and compassion reached to all people. He healed a Roman centurion’s servant (Luke 7:1–10). He traveled through the Gentile region of the Gerasenes (Mark 5:1). He ministered in a Samaritan city (John 4).

And there's a hint from [John 10:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+10%3A16&version=CSB) that Jesus refers to the Gentiles as "other sheep that are not from this sheep pen":

> But I have **other sheep that are not from this sheep pen**; I must bring them also, and they will listen to my voice. Then there will be one flock, one shepherd.

Out of this one flock of sheep, the wicked are those who don't believe Jesus and not included in the flock.  [John 10:25-27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+10%3A25-27&version=CSB):

> “I did tell you and you don’t believe,” Jesus answered them. “The works that I do in my Father’s name testify about me. But you don’t believe because you are not of my sheep. My sheep hear my voice, I know them, and they follow me.

[John 10:28-30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+10%3A28-30&version=CSB) emphasizes that the flock (consisting of Jews and Gentiles) were entrusted to Jesus by God the Father:

> I give them eternal life, and they will never perish. No one will snatch them out of my hand. **My Father, who has given them to me, is greater than all. No one is able to snatch them out of the Father’s hand.** I and the Father are one.”

#### After Resurrection

But it's only after Jesus's Resurrection that it became clear that bringing the gospel to "all nations" has been God's plan all along, who gave Jesus that authority in v. 18.  [Matt 28:18-20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+28%3A18-20&version=CSB):

> <sup>18</sup> Jesus came near and said to them, “All authority has been given to me in heaven and on earth. <sup>19</sup> Go, therefore, and **make disciples of all nations**, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, <sup>20</sup> teaching them to observe everything I have commanded you. And remember, I am with you always, to the end of the age.”

#### Conclusion

The books of Proverbs and the Psalms were intended for the Israelite society to teach their young so they don't become wicked.  Your mistake is to equate the wicked with the Gentiles; the wicked is a **separate category**.  There are wicked Jews and Gentiles alike, although to the wicked Israelites God sent them prophets to warn them, showing that God paid special attention to Israel **first**, His chosen people.  [Eph 2:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+2&version=CSB):

> At that time [Old Testament] you [Gentiles] were without Christ, excluded from the citizenship of Israel, and foreigners to the covenants of promise, without hope and without God in the world.

You are correct that Jesus obeyed God and taught only what God taught, but as you can see above, God Himself planned to include the Gentiles in the New Covenant that Jesus established and in the New Kingdom that Jesus inaugurated for the Church's mission to expand by the power of the Holy Spirit poured on the Church at Pentecost.  In addition, Paul made it crystal clear in several of his letters that Jews and Gentiles are united in Christ ([Rom 11:13-24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom+11%3A13-24&version=CSB) about Gentiles being grafted to the Olive tree and [Eph 2:11-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+2%3A11-21&version=CSB) about Unity of the two groups in Christ).  **Since it's obvious that God loves Israel, now that the Gentiles become part of God's people, God loves the Gentiles too.**

Answer (score 2):

This answer is in two parts:

- The Old Testament affirms God's love for all people
- Jesus repeated and ratified the same

**Old Testament**

Psalm 145:

```
8 The Lord is gracious and merciful,
    slow to anger and abounding in steadfast love.
9 The Lord is good to all,
    and his mercy is over all that he has made.
```

In the Old Testament, the longest speech that God delivered was to Job. God extended his life by 140 years and multiplied his wealth and rebuilt his family. Job was not Jewish.

In Genesis, the first person to enter heaven without dying was Enoch (before the flood). Enoch was not Jewish.

In 2 Kings 5, the general Naaman was healed of leprosy by Elijah. Naaman was Syrian and conquered parts of Israel for his king.

In 1 Kings 17, Elijah performed miracles for the widow of Zarephath, making her jars of flour and of oil to not run out until a lengthy drought ended and then resurrecting her son from the dead! She was a Sidonian.

In Jonah, at the reluctant preaching of the Jewish prophet, 120,000 citizens of Nineveh were spared God's wrath. They were Assyrians, the arch enemies of Israel.

In Genesis, after Abraham sent Hagar, his wife's slave away, along with his son Ishmael, God sent an angel to show her a spring of water and preserve their lives. They gave rise to the Arab peoples.

God extends His love to all people. However, if they reject it, they will ultimately suffer the consequences.

**New Testament**

In Luke 4, Jesus recalls the stories of Naaman and the widow:

> 20 And he rolled up the scroll and gave it back to the attendant and
> sat down. And the eyes of all in the synagogue were fixed on him. 21
> And he began to say to them, “Today this Scripture has been fulfilled
> in your hearing.” 22 And all spoke well of him and marveled at the
> gracious words that were coming from his mouth. And they said, “Is not
> this Joseph's son?” 23 And he said to them, “Doubtless you will quote
> to me this proverb, ‘“Physician, heal yourself.” What we have heard
> you did at Capernaum, do here in your hometown as well.’” 24 And he
> said, “Truly, I say to you, no prophet is acceptable in his hometown.
> 25 But in truth, I tell you, there were many widows in Israel in the
> days of Elijah, when the heavens were shut up three years and six
> months, and a great famine came over all the land, 26 and **Elijah was
> sent to none of them but only to Zarephath, in the land of Sidon, to a
> woman who was a widow**. 27 **And there were many lepers in Israel in
> the time of the prophet Elisha, and none of them was cleansed, but
> only Naaman the Syrian.**” 28 When they heard these things, all in the
> synagogue were filled with wrath. 29 And they rose up and drove him
> out of the town and brought him to the brow of the hill on which their
> town was built, so that they could throw him down the cliff. 30 But
> passing through their midst, he went away.

Not only did Jesus emphasize God's love for people besides the Jews, they nearly killed him for it on the spot. Taking such a risk means that Jesus really meant what he said.